# In which StackExchange site to appropriate ask for a programming framework?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I know it is not appropriate to ask for "which tool or framework to use" in SO.
Unfortunately I do not know where is the place of such kind of questions?

For example:

"Is there any JavaScript framework for browser based interactive workflow drawing?"

PS: If this very question I mean ("In which StackExchange site to appropriate ask for a programming framework?") is not appropriate here, the where is the place to ask "where can I ask"

Comment: [softwarerecs.se]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest fit would be [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

However, before you post there I'd urge you to carefully read [What is required for a question to contain “enough information”?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/352) on the site's Meta. If your question doesn't have enough detail it'll probably get closed quickly, even if it belongs on the site topically.

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between asking "Which tool to use?" (asking for opinions) and "Is there any such tool as...?" (asking for generic information).

Both are off-topic for SO though, since they are provoking opinion and are prone to spam respectively. The answer to the second question can also easily be found by using a search engine like [Google](https://www.google.com/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=HltEVq7iGNGKOqrDnMAE#q=JavaScript+framework+for+browser+based+interactive+workflow+drawing).

Such topics could however be discussed in the SO [chat channels](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) if it falls within in the channel's set topic. The chat is a place where you can talk socially with other developers and ask about such things. Might help you get a developers insight on your question, rather than one generated by a search algorithm.